# Audio guided meditation recommendations?

Tags: personal-practice, modern-world, media, guidance

I know how many of you feel about guided meditations, but I am introducing meditation to some fellow university friends, and one of them is telling me he is having an incredibly hard time while sitting in silence. He asked me for some audio guided meditations so that he can ease his way into silent meditation, and still be able to sit with us.

I have never used one before, so I have no idea. Would you have any to recommend?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "[How To Meditate](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL603BD0B03E12F5A1)" YouTube video playlist by Yuttadhammo Bhikkhu is highly recommended. It includes both sitting and walking meditation. This is more like vipassana meditation based on the four foundations of mindfulness.

Another good YouTube video is "[Guided Breath Meditation](https://youtu.be/z2y9N3IdEqY)" by Thanissaro Bhikkhu. This is more like a body scanning meditation.

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much for your suggestion

Comment: Unfortunately, Yuttadhammo's method of meditation is not as taught in the Suttas. For example, "cittanupassana" is not merely experiencing thoughts or formations, but moods and defilements. The third tetrad is not achieved easily.

Comment: Why not? Please see [this page](https://www.sirimangalo.org/text/how-to-meditate/chapter-two-sitting-meditation/) for details. For example "*When happiness arises, one should create the clear thought, “happy.” When one feels peaceful or calm, one should create the clear thought, “peaceful,” or “calm” until that feeling goes away.*"

Comment: This has nothing to do with the four tretrads which are found in the Anapanasati Sutta. The last step of the 'Kaya' for example has Piti as its object, which resulted in a quite mind. Then, after Piti has arisen, it becomes the main object of meditation. This results in the transition from Kayanupassana to Vedanapassana. If the four tretrads really can be practised as you mentioned, how then do you explain piti in the kaya section or the last tetrad, 'Dhammanupassana"? Vipassana &Samatha go hand in hand. Vipassana is seeing the 5 aggregates as impermanent & non-self. This results in dispassion

Comment: This part of the video can be helpful(6:40-7:38): https://youtu.be/GDDY4gOexVA?t=400

Comment: The meditation video by Yuttadhammo Bhikkhu is just basic formal meditation, based on the four foundations of mindfulness. **It's meant for beginners.** It covers the basics of the mindfulness of breathing and the basics of each of the four foundations of mindfulness. For the foundation of dhammas, it covers only the five hindrances. So, I think it is as taught in the suttas, just that it is at the basic level for the beginner. Furthermore, you should look at Satipatthana Sutta, not Anapanasati Sutta.

Answer (score 2):

Ajahn Jayasaro has a lot of Dhamma talks, Q&As and guided meditation sessions. Just look up on YouTube.

Answer (score 1):

Tell your friend to try out the headspace app. It's very beginner friendly and it helps create a sense on progression.

https://www.headspace.com/meditation-101/what-is-meditation

Answer (score 1):

Nyom Pedros,

[First Things First!](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/thanissaro/index_en.html)

It's totally wise of your friend to seek after "audio guided 'meditation'" since path and right view does not come from 'meditation', but right meditation is caused by right view and comes naturally. And what is the cause of right view? Listening to the good Dhamma and having proper attention, since requiring to leave home, stand, at first place.

Hard to find the good Dhamma under so many wellness-Dhamma and trades of many kinds for favors... and hard to hold at this time proper attention, but here the advice of the Sublime Buddha how to get a "Audio guided meditation", the Buddhas recommendation on your question:

> "There is the case, Bharadvaja, where a monk lives in dependence on a certain village or town. Then a householder or householder's son goes to him and observes him with regard to three mental qualities — qualities based on greed, qualities based on aversion, qualities based on delusion... [The Way to Stream Entry](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/study/into_the_stream_en.html#part1)

Certain guided meditations which are not just focusing on a certain marked, but on right view, a "tabu" under so called meditator, can be found at: https://www.dhammatalks.org/ and yes, also for the marked is plenty on food.

Maybe starting with a talk on basics like [Generosity](https://www.dhammatalks.org/Archive/Lectures/IMC/20090503-Thanissaro_Bhikkhu-IMC-generosity.mp3) or even better in sound and script: [Respect, Confidence and Patient](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/thanissaro/respectconfidencepatient_en.html)

*{Note: This is not given for any usual trade, exchange, stacks or Buddh-ism but simply to free one self and go beyond and may be deleted if not seeking for such here, i.e. not given for you.}*